# Construct a non-constant analytic function $f : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ or show that this is impossible.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am having a lot of difficulty with the following past qualifying exam problem.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Let
$\Omega_1 = \mathbb{C}\setminus \left \{\{0\} \cup \{\dfrac{1}{n}:n\in \Bbb N\}\right \}$
and
$\Omega_2 = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{z : \text{Im } z=0,\ |\text{Re} z|\ge 1\}.$
Construct a non-constant analytic function $f : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ or show that this is impossible.

Comment: How can you even talk about a holomorphic (analytic) function if your set is not open?

Comment: They are open sets.

Comment: Oh that is much better. The backslash makes all the difference!

Comment: For future reference, to make $\mathbb{C}$, use the command \mathbb{C} and to make $\setminus$, write \setminus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Omega_2$ is biholomorphic to the open unit disc, so the problem is equivalent to constructing a non-constant holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega_1$ with absolute value $<1$. Now each of $1/n$ would be an isolated singularity of $g$, and as $g$ is bounded, each of them is removable, i.e. $g$ extends to $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. But then $0$ is an isolated singularity for this extended function which is still bounded, so $g$ extends to an entire bounded function, hence $g$ is constant by Liouville theorem.